# Dependency and Association are one and the same?

Tags: java, dependencies, associations

I guess this is a very fundamental question, but I have not been able to get clarity. I started creating UML diagrams for a project and noticed that all the associations were not displayed (according to me). After reading through different sites, I understood that non-displayed ones are called **Dependencies**. But despite reading through various sites, I could not understand how Dependency is different from Association? So based on what I thought is explained, I created 3 simple classes:

```
public class ClassA {
    private String newS;
    public void setNewS (String para1)
    {
       newS = para1;
    }
}
```

An associated class:

```
public class AssociatesWithA {
     ClassA _classA = new ClassA();
     void main()
     {
         _classA.setNewS("dummy");
     }
}
```

and a Dependent class:

```
public class DependsOnA {
    public void UseA(ClassA varClassA)
    {
        varClassA.setNewS("something");
    }
}
```

I dragged all the above to create a UML model and as expected I saw a solid line between ClassA *and* AssociatesWithA **and** dashed line between ClassA *and* DependsOnA. But why? In both the classes I am using **setNewS** of ClassA.

As far as I can see, **AssociatesWithA** also depends on **ClassA** as if the implementation of method **setNewS** is modified in ClassA, then **AssociatesWithA** will break. So isn't Dependency just a different way of implementing Association?

Answer (score 0):

Association and dependency are absolutely different things.
However, the association in model represents existence of relationship in real world, for example friendship, dependency element in model is used to keep uml model consistent. Dependency does not have representation in real world.

I recommend you to read UML superstructure to get detailed knowledge about relationship types in UML